# Running tests in Maven, without classes and just jars

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, surefire

I have this strange request for a proceedure. Basicly we want to be able to run tests using a method like

```
mvn surefire:test failsafe:test
```

which will only perform testing. The problem is we want to do this on a system that the target dirs don't contain the classes. I have figured out a possible way of doing this by running with the

```
<additionalClasspathElements>
```

option in the surefire plugin and putting access to the jars. Problem is this is difficult to find. Is there another way to run tests without having access to the class files and just the jars?

Comment: Who puts test classes in their packaged jars?

Comment: @Mark many people, usually in separate jars with a classifier.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski Care to back that up with something more substantial? I fail to see the usefulness of bloating jar files with test classes, or creating a distributable jar with nothing but test classes.